# How to enable disable textboxes when particular checkbox is checked through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

For this page:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked id="chk1" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" checked id="chk2" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" checked id="chk3" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" checked id="chk4" onclick="myFunction(this)" />

<input type="text" id="txt1" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" id="txt4" disabled="disabled" />

<script>
    function myFunction(el) {
        var txt = document.getElementById(el.id.replace('chk', 'txt'));

        if (el.checked) {
            document.getElementById(txt).removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
        else
            document.getElementById(txt).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
</script>
```

I have tried this script but it is giving error as

> "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is
>   null or not an object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction(el) {
    var txt = document.getElementById(el.id.replace('chk', 'txt'));

    if (el.checked) {
        txt.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
    else
        txt.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

[See working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e1qaLg3y/). If it still doesn't work for yo, simply move your script above html mark up.

Comment: Textboxs are not enabled using this script

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your script section:

```
var txt = document.getElementById(el.id.replace('chk', 'txt'));
```

This gives you back the whole element of the `textbox` not the id. If you change to this it should work:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(el) {
        var txt = el.id.replace('chk', 'txt');

        if (el.checked) {
            document.getElementById(txt).removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
        else
            document.getElementById(txt).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
</script>
```

You can test it in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzb5yj7L/2/) (do note that I also removed the `checked` property of your `checkboxes` in the fiddle example)

Answer (score 0):

user with `var txt = el.id.replace('chk', 'txt');`

instead of 
 `var txt = document.getElementById(el.id.replace('chk', 'txt'));`

No need to use `document.getElementById` because you are already declare with element in `myFunction(this)`

And apply `disabled` with `true | false`

```js
function myFunction(el) {
        var txt = el.id.replace('chk', 'txt');


        if (el.checked ) {
            document.getElementById(txt).disabled = false;
        }
        else
            document.getElementById(txt).disabled = true;
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked id="chk1" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" checked id="chk2" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" checked  id="chk3" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" checked id="chk4" onclick="myFunction(this)" />

<input type="text" id="txt1" disabled>
<input type="text" id="txt2" disabled>
<input type="text" id="txt3" disabled>
<input type="text" id="txt4" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this statement you will het the textbox

```
var txt = document.getElementById(el.id.replace('chk', 'txt'))
```

BUt then you should not use this

```
document.getElementById(txt).removeAttribute("disabled");
```

but this

```
txt.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

For example see fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/zxrxcs5k/